# if x is an Angular component then verify its part of this module

Tags: angular

I have created an Angular application. I have put the selector of the navigation component in the app.component.html which is part of the app.module and getting the following error.

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-nav' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-nav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

The app-nav is the selector of navcomponent which belongs to the sharedmodule. The sharedmodule is imported to the app.module.

So why isnt the app-nav not being recognized ?

**NavComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**Shared module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**App module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OrderModule } from './modules/order/order.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OrderModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-nav> </app-nav>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the shared module does not exports the component.
Add `exports: [NavComponent]` to your shared module.
When you add a component or a module in your shared module, do not forget to add it in the `exports` array.